# Loop over file names in a subdirectory that have periods, but exclude the path and file extension

Tags: bash, filenames

I have a bash script in directory `./`. This directory contains the directory `output`. Within `output` are files such as...

```
Alabama.txt
U.S. Virgin Islands.txt
```

How do I loop thru the files in `output` and print the following output

```
Alabama
U.S. Virgin Islands
```

Comment: That gives me the whole path and file extensions, which I do not want.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have problems with reading comprehension. `cd output; for file in *; do echo ${file%.*}; done`. This strips the last dot and all following characters from the file name.

Comment: Ah I see. But I cannot use `cd` in this project. Sorry, I should have mentioned that up front.

Comment: This is a strange requirement. Is `pushd` and `popd`allowed? If not, you can easily strip `output/` from the output using a similar expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
for pathname in output/*.txt; do
    basename "$pathname" .txt
done
```

The `basename` utility takes a pathname and removes any directory component from it, leaving only the final filename component.  It also takes a string as an optional second argument.  This string will be trimmed off from the end of the given pathname.

We use `basename` in the loop over all names matching `output/*.txt` to remove the `output/` part of the pathname and to remove the `.txt` filename suffix.  This leaves only the "stem" of the filename, which is outputted.

You may achieve the same effect using built-in standard parameter substitutions:

```bsh
for pathname in output/*.txt; do
    name=${pathname#output/}
    printf '%s\n' "${name%.txt}"
done
```

This performs two parameter substitutions on each pathname that `output/*.txt` expands to; one to remove the initial `output/` substring and a second to remove the trailing `.txt` substring.

If there is any risk that the `output` directory might be empty of files with a `.txt` filename suffix, then you may want to set the `nullglob` shell option (using `shopt -s nullglob`).  This would prevent the above loops from running a single time, which they would otherwise do (with the unexpanded pattern `output/*.txt` in `$pathname`).

You may also want to set the `dotglob` shell option if you want to match hidden names in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
print -rC1 -- output/*.*(N:t:r)
```

Where `print -rC1 --` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn and `(N:t:r)` are glob qualifiers with, `N` to enable `nullglob` (for the glob to expand to nothing if there's no matching file) and `:t`, `:r` are csh-like modifiers to get the `t`ail and `r`oot of the file (remove the directory part and extension).

Add the `D`  glob qualifier if you also want to include hidden files (in which case you'd likely want to change `*.*` to `?*.*` to make sure those hidden files have an extension.

With any shell, but with the GNU implementation of `basename`, and assuming all the files you're interested in are not hidden and have a `.txt` extension, that `output` contains at least one such file, and that the list of files is not too big so as not to exceed the `execve()` limit on the size of args+env, you could also do:

```
basename -as.txt output/*.txt
```

With `bash` (the GNU shell) specifically, and with the GNU implementation of `sed`, you could also do:

```
(
  shopt -s dotglob nullglob
  printf '%s\0' output/?*.* |
    LC_ALL=C sed -z 's:.*/::; s/\.[^.]*$//' |
    tr '\0' '\n'
)
```

For an approximation of the `zsh` one that includes hidden files.